# Multivariate time series modelling in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I want do fit some sort of multi-variate time series model using R.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
   u     cci     bci     cpi     gdp    dum1 dum2 dum3    dx  
 16.50   14.00   53.00   45.70   80.63  0   0    1     6.39 
 17.45   16.00   64.00   46.30   80.90  0   0    0     6.00 
 18.40   12.00   51.00   47.30   82.40  1   0    0     6.57 
 19.35   7.00    42.00   48.40   83.38  0   1    0     5.84 
 20.30   9.00    34.00   49.50   84.38  0   0    1     6.36 
 20.72   10.00   42.00   50.60   85.17  0   0    0     5.78 
 21.14   6.00    45.00   51.90   85.60  1   0    0     5.16 
 21.56   9.00    38.00   52.60   86.14  0   1    0     5.62 
 21.98   2.00    32.00   53.50   86.23  0   0    1     4.94 
 22.78   8.00    29.00   53.80   86.24  0   0    0     6.25
```

The data is quarterly, the dummy variables are for seasonality.

What I would like to do is to predict dx with reference to some of the others, while (possibly) allowing for seasonality. For argument's sake, lets say I want to use "u", "cci" and "gdp".

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, have a look at [the time series view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html), especially the section on multivariate time series.

In finance, one traditional way of doing this is with a factor model, frequently with either a BARRA or Fama-French type model.  Eric Zivot's ["Modeling financial time series with S-PLUS"](http://books.google.com/books?id=sxODP2l1mX8C) gives a good overview of these topics, but it isn't immediately transferable into R.  Ruey Tsay's "[Analysis of Financial Time Series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471690740)" (available in the TSA package on CRAN) also has a nice discussion of factor models and principal component analysis in chapter 9.

R also has a number of packages that cover [vector autoregression (VAR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) models.  In particular, I would recommend looking at Bernhard Pfaff's [VAR Modelling (vars)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/index.html) package and [the related vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf).

I strongly recommend looking at [**Ruey Tsay's homepage**](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/) because it covers all these topics, and provides the necessary R code.  In particular, look at the ["Applied Multivariate Analysis"](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/ama/), ["Analysis of Financial Time Series"](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/bs41202/sp2009/), and ["Multivariate Time Series Analysis"](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/mts/sp2009/) courses.

This is a very large subject and there are many good books that cover it, including both multivariate time series forcasting and seasonality.  Here are a few more:

1. Kleiber and Zeileis. "[Applied Econometrics with R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387773169)" doesn't address this specifically, but it covers the overall subject very well (see also the AER package on CRAN).
2. Shumway and Stoffer. "[Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387293175)" has examples of multivariate ARIMA models.
3. Cryer. "[Time Series Analysis: With Applications in R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387759581)" is a classic on the subject, updated to include R code.

Answer (score 6):

In the forecast package, try:

```
arima(df[,1:4], order=(0,0,0), xreg=df[,6:8])
```

for forecasting `u`, `cci` and `gdp`.

To predict `dx` from that, try the VAR model. Here's a good tutorial ([**PDF**](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/varModels.pdf)).

Comment: i'm afraid this is not working; error message: "Error in arima(data[, 1:4], order = c(0, 0, 0), xreg = data[, 6:8]) : 
  only implemented for univariate time series"

Comment: Yes, it's only for univariate and don't forget `order=c(0,0,0)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't Know if this functionality was available when you first asked this question but this is easily available in base R now with the arima function; just specify your external regressors with the xreg argument within the function. Try `?arima` and when you read the documentation pay special attention to the xreg argument. This has been made very easy, good luck.

Comment: According to the documentation, Arima only supports univariate time series. OP has a multivariate time series.