# Time series with gaps in time variable / missing dates

Tags: r, time-series, data-analysis

I have a dataset having multiple variables. My first column is `date` (date is reported daily but it's missing for few days randomly) and rest are other variables. I want to convert this dataframe to time-series (ts) type. I tried `ts()` function but it didn't work as `ts()` is useful for regularly spaced time series.

Please suggest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714280/multivariate-time-series-modelling-in-r

Answer (score 2):

`zoo`, from the `zoo` package, can be used to represent multivariate time-series.

Install it using:

```
install.packages("zoo")
```

Example of a two column `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)

zoo(matrix(c(1, 20, 3, 91, 3, 15, 8, 33), ncol = 2), order.by = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-06")))
```

Comment: I suggest using xts package instead of directly using zoo because it offers greater performance and functionality.