# Preprocessing multivariate time-series

Tags: python, r, time-series, r-caret

Assume that I have indexed by time observations of a group of variables.

```
   A        B      C       D     ...    V   day
 16.50   14.00   53.00   45.70   ...  6.39   1
 17.45   16.00   64.00   46.30   ...  6.00   2
 18.40   12.00   51.00   47.30   ...  6.57   3
 19.35   7.00    42.00   48.40   ...  5.84   4
 20.30   9.00    34.00   49.50   ...  6.36   5
 20.72   10.00   42.00   50.60   ...  5.78   6
 21.14   6.00    45.00   51.90   ...  5.16   7
 21.56   9.00    38.00   52.60   ...  5.62   8
 21.98   2.00    32.00   53.50   ...  4.94   9
 22.78   8.00    29.00   53.80   ...  6.25   10
 ...
```

Based on this data frame, I would like to construct a predictive model for a target Variable V with predictors being some of the other variables *from previous observations,* say with a time-horizon [image].  That is, I would like to fit a model of this type

[image] ,

where [image] is the error, and [image] is chosen from a certain class of functions (e.g. a some kind of a neural network or a tree based method).

**Question** Are there packages that allow me a flexible choice of a learning algorithm, possibly from other packages, while also doing necessary preprocessing? Something in the spirit of what Caret does.

**Thoughts** Of course I could add a bunch of columns to the data frame, say A1, A2, ..., AK, etc, where say A1 is the value of A on the previous day, A2 is the value of A from 2 days before, etc. After that, I could apply any package I'd like. The problem is that if my initial data frame is large, this new data frame is going to be many times larger (about [image] times, to be precise). This makes such an approach very inefficient if [image]  is large.

Caret package does have the function called `createTimeSlices`, but it seems to be designed for  univariate time-series. This question is similar to [this older one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714280/multivariate-time-series-modelling-in-r) from 2009. The packages recommended there do not quite seem to do what I described above. I was wondering whether other tools have appeared since then. I would also appreciate any information if something like this exist in python.

Comment: As far as R packages go, I would try 'marima', and 'MARSS'.  I haven't tried 'MARSS', but 'marima', will require some understanding of univariate ARIMA modeling.